# DB integrity when ios and android app update at different time

Tags: android, ios, database

I am wondering whether I should still following traditional DB recommendation  when dealing with app development. (e.g. setting "not null" constraints)

Consider the following situation:

I have an app for both iOS and Android, which is able to upload data to a remote server. Then, if there is a enhancement in the future, for example, add a new mandatory field to the upload function.

If that new filed is set as "**not null**" in remote db, then the app will crash when users perform the upload function with a non-updated app.
It is common that user not always update their apps.

Another situation is that when enhancement on iOS and android versions are released on different schedule, how to ensure that the "not null" filed wont cased any problem?

Currently, my workaround would be avoiding those "not null" constraints. So, users will be able to use the upload function with updated or non-updated app.

But I would love to know if there is a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could: 1) On the server, check your update data for the presence of the new field - if missing, supply a default value in the input data; 2) Create a new table that contains the new field(s). If it is an old version, only update the old table, if new update new and old tables.  Use join to combine data as needed.

Comment: Also, whenever you send messages through a self made API, you want to have one field that contains the version number of your API, so that in the future, you'll be able to tell the format from the version number, and code on your server accordingly.